# UDP client/server chat

Tags: java, client, chat

I am planning to make a Java chat messenger. But I am facing a problem. It is that the client side cannot send a message until it receives a message from the server side program. how do I fix this?

I have different code for server side and client side. 
This is my client side program.

```
  DatagramPacket send_packet = new DatagramPacket(send_data,
                                                  send_data.length, 
                                                  IPAddress, 5020);
  client_socket.send(send_packet);
  DatagramPacket dpacket = new DatagramPacket(recv_data, recv_data.length);
  client_socket.receive(dpacket);
  String msg = new String(dpacket.getData(),0,dpacket.getLength());
  System.out.println("Aman2: \n" + msg);
```

Comment: did you consider running receiver and sender on different threads?

Comment: Why does it have to be this way?  The client could just know where the server is and the port to use.  You might want to use this library: http://netty.io/